# connecting two combobox with eachother

Tags: c#, mysql

i managed to fill the first combobox1 with names , but i dont know how to fill the combox2 , i want the program to show me the dates that where stored under the same patientname in my data base and then to show me the address in a testbox1 for example my table is :

patientname   date     address

dell           3/2014    Tokyo

dell           3/2009     Paris

jack           4/2003      USA

dell          4 /2007       Sweden

so when i choose dell from combobox1 it should show me in combox2 the dates ( 3/2014, 4/2003 , 4/2007 ) and when i choose any one of them it should show me in the textbox1 the address under this date

from what i wrote in code i was able to see the patientname in combox1 but i didnt know how to show the dates in combox2  , my code :

```
void Fillcombo() {

        string constring = "datasource=localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=root";

        string Query = " select * from  database.check WHERE patientname  IS NOT NULL ;";
        MySqlConnection conDataBase = new MySqlConnection(constring);
        MySqlCommand cmdDatabase = new MySqlCommand(Query, conDataBase);
        MySqlDataReader myReader;
        try
        {
            conDataBase.Open();
            myReader = cmdDatabase.ExecuteReader();

            while (myReader.Read())
            {
                string sname = myReader.GetString("patientname");
                comboBox1.Items.Add(sname);

                string sdate = myReader.GetString("date where patientname ='" + this.comboBox1.Text + "' ");
                comboBox2.Items.Add(sdate)                    
            }
        }
```

Comment: Don't use two combobox use one and an item.template to display both values.

Comment: will this work instead `string sname = (string)myReader["patientname"];`

Comment: blam - could you  demonstrate that ?!

Comment: @user3810508 I posted an answer an hour ago

Answer (score 0):

Create a patient class with properties sname and sdate
Bind to a List of patient
Use ItemTempate/DataTemplate to display the two values

[ItemsControl.ItemTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemtemplate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: could you explain what to do in details ?

Comment: No SO is not a code generation tool.  What have you tried?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347(v=vs.110).aspx